# Nested Model Form in Play Framework

Tags: playframework

I have a schema that goes Event -has one-> Location and I want to create a form that will allow me to create an event and while doing so select a location from a drop down list or create a new one if the location does not exist in the drop down box.

I know this is possible in Rails with the fields_for helper, but is there something similar in Play?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You should go trough the [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/Home) and included samples (ie. Computer Database) to learn basic possibilities. Play is just a helper for programming language, so yes, everything is possible.

Check mentioned docs and samples to see the basics of working with forms, models, etc.

Comment: I did read the documentation, but I guess I should go through the examples like you said. Thanks for the response.